# publishing Next.js project as npm - Can't resolve module

Tags: typescript, next.js, npm-package

I have a Next.js 13.4 project A that I publish to local npm. I'm using the app router

I have created a index.js that export a react component like:
`export { default as MainPage } from "./app/components/templates/MainPage";`

Inside the MainPage component there are child components that use imports that are based on baseUrl in tsconfig.json = "baseUrl": "./app".

For example a child component contain an import that uses this baseUrl:

`import useConfig from "hooks/useConfig";`

The hooks folder is placed inside the app dir so ./app/hooks/useConfig. But i works find the the local VS Code project, but when I try to publish the project to our local npm repository, errors occur.

I have another Next.js project B that consumes this npm package and it can use the MainPage component, but when I try to build it with npm run build error occurs with
`./node_modules/..app/layout/MainLayout/Drawer/DrawerContent/Navigation/NavCollapse.tsx Module not found: Can't resolve 'hooks/useConfig'`

There are many other places where these absolute imports are used in project A, so it would be nice to have some sort of configuration in the project, instead of converting them all to relative imports..

Isn't there a way to configure that these absolute imports are found correctly in Next.js project A?
Maybe something in next.config.js?

I was expecting that when I publish Next.js project A and was exporting MainPage through index.js and index.d.ts, it was possible to have another Next.js project use this MainPage with errors.

Comment: [`"baseUrl"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) allows TypeScript to understand these imports but it doesn't provide them. Your runtime environment has to handle that

Comment: OK but that is the question - how do I handle it?

Comment: Nextjs is weird. Apparently it does some automatic setup based on those options. I haven't worked with it enough to say but this looks like the documentation page you're looking for https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases